# Mysql, check if array combination exists (participants in thread)

Tags: mysql

I have a table like so :

```
| thread_id | user_id |
+-----------+---------+
|     1     |    1    |
|     1     |    2    |
|     2     |    1    |
|     2     |    3    |
|     3     |    1    |
|     3     |    3    |
|     3     |    2    |
           ...
```

How would I check if an array combination exists and belongs to the same thread ?

Ex:

```
1,3     => return true
3,1,2   => return true
1,4,2,3 => return false
```

Arrays could contain several hundred id's, with hundreds of thounds of threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT NULL
WHERE  EXISTS (
           SELECT   NULL
           FROM     your_table
           WHERE    user_id IN (1,2,3,4,..., ...)
           GROUP BY thread_id
           HAVING   COUNT(*) = n
       )
```

Where `n` is the count of items in the list / array.

Then in your script:

- If a row was returned: `true`
- Else:                  `false`

Comment: Number of items in array list, nice. Thank you.